# How to get unique record based on due date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying this query to get unique rows based on ID_B but I also want ID_B where DueDate is nearest, this is what I am trying,

```
SELECT distinct ID_B, ID_A, Own_ID, DueDate FROM  Table1 WHERE (ID_A = 6155)
```

Result I am getting,

[image]

***I want unique ID_B with earliest Due Date.***

For example In result pane, I only want ONE ID_B record for ID_B = 1 with DueDate = 2014-07-21 10:54:02.027

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
;with cte as
(select id_b, id_a, own_id, duedate,
 row_number() over (partition by isnull(id_b,0) order by duedate) rn
 from yourtable
 where id_a = 6155)

select id_b,id_a,own_id,duedate from cte
where rn = 1
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/DHPCEK71622)

Comment: Must specify table to select from.

Comment: it giving me empty set now

Comment: now it works thanks, can you tell me how to hide rn from output pleazo

Comment: You shouldn't be getting `rn` with the query I have posted here. In any case, you can just specify all the columns by name, like we do when selecting from a table.

Answer (score 0):

You can write as:

```
;with CTE as 
( Select ID_B,
         ID_A,
         DueDate,        
         Row_number() over ( partition by ID_B order by [DueDate] asc) as rownum
         from Table1
 ) 
 select ID_B, ID_A,DueDate
 from CTE C
 where C.rownum = 1 and ID_A = 6155 and ISNULL(ID_B,0)<>0
```

[Check Demo here..](http://rextester.com/MHSCTR53582)

Comment: Thank you deep, but everytime i run your query in my dataset I get empty data set

Comment: Please check the demo link and let me know the data you have that's missing there ..I have written the query based on the sample data posted here..

Answer (score -1):

Try the below query

```
-- create table
Create Table Table5 (ID_A int, ID_B int, Own_ID int identity, Due_date datetime)

-- insert the values into the newly created tbale
insert into Table5 values (1,100,GETDATE())
insert into Table5 values (1,100,GETDATE()+1)
insert into Table5 values (1,100,GETDATE()+2)

insert into Table5 values (1,200,GETDATE())
insert into Table5 values (1,200,GETDATE()+1)
insert into Table5 values (1,200,GETDATE()+2)

-- Query to fetch the nearest record 
Select * from 
(
Select Row_number()over( partition by ID_B order by Due_date desc) as row ,* from Table5
) as temp
where temp.row = 1
```

Comment: Actually query needs to sort with Due_date. query has updated now